# Merge grouped generic lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();

fooList.Add(new Foo(){
    Id = 1,
    Bar = 1,
    Blah = 1
});

fooList.Add(new Foo(){
    Id = 1,
    Bar = 2,
    Blah = 1
});

fooList.Add(new Foo(){
    Id = 2,
    Bar = 1,
    Blah = 2
});
```

If I group my `fooList` by the `Id` property, all properties except `Bar` are equal to each other for each group. I noticed that there is a `GroupMy` lambda method, but is there any way to group the lists by `Id`, and make the `Bar` property a list of all the `Bar`s for each id?

Because right now i have a lot of redundant data on each row. Please let me know if you want me to elaborate the problem.

Comment: A query cannot change the structure of a class, so since `Bar` is an `int`, how should the query change it to an `IEnumerable<int>`? (_"is there any way to group the lists by Id, and **make the Bar property a list of all the Bars** for each id"_)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Would it help to change the type to `dynamic`?

Comment: You could do: `fooList.ToLookup (x => x.Id, x => x.Bar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) extension that lets you determine the element selector:

```
var query = fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Id, f => f.Bar);

// Iterate over each grouping in the collection. 
foreach (var group in query)
{
    // Print the key value.
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    // Iterate over each value in the  
    // grouping and print the value. 
    foreach (int bar in group)
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", bar);
}
```

Or if you want `Bar` to be an explicit property:

```
var query = fooList.GroupBy(
    f => f.Id, 
    (id, foos) => new {Id = id, Bars = foos.Select(f=>f.Bar)});
```

Though I find that a little hard to read.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the `Bar` values sorted as I would like, but what about the rest of the properties for each row?

Comment: @Johan That is what a normal `GroupBy` (without the element selector) would give you.

Comment: This is probably as close as i can get to what i need with my somewhat poor explanation :) thank you